# How do I use custom logic in Identity Server 4 to limit who can be issued an id token or access token

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect, implicit-flow

I've got a SPA written with with Angular, and it communicates with a few APIs (also owned by me) to do all of its work.  To secure the application, I am using Identity Server 4 with AAD as the single external provider.

I'm using a route guard in Angular that initiates the oidc implicit flow if the user is not yet authenticated before navigating to a route.  This is all working great -- the user is forced to login with AAD before any of the "secure" routes can be accessed.

**A new requirement for the application is that only a subset of the users in our AAD tenant are allowed to use the application**.  Within AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback (from quickstart UI), I am able to make this determination using claims that are being returned from AAD.  Once I've determined whether or not it's a valid user, I can't figure out what to do from there to fail the authentication and return a response to my SPA that will allow me to show an "unauthorized" view.

Is this possible?  Does my workflow need to change to meet this new requirement, or is there a way to inject this custom logic into Identity Server somewhere?